# Android KEYCODE_DEL not firing as expected for hardware keyboard

Tags: android

I'm making a custom editor on Android. Let's suppose I have a bit of code like this:

```
package com.example.backspace

import android.util.Log
import android.view.KeyEvent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.e("KEY", "Keypress: $keyCode")
        return true
    }
}
```

If I start the app and try the backspace key it shows up fine. If I instead type a single character first, then try the backspace key, the backspace key will not register. Pressing backspace again registers it again.

Similarly, if I type 2 characters, I need to press backspace key 3 times for it to register once. And then it continues to register.

I need to capture it in 100% of the times it's pressed. What am I missing?

Comment: why use onKeyDown and not a text change listener on a EditText?

Comment: @UrielFrankel Because I'm writing my own editor, that has special needs.